# SwiftyJSON Redundant Conformance Error

Tags: ios8, xcode7, swifty-json

SwiftyJSON.swift file is giving me an error of Redundant conformance of 'NSNumber' to protocol 'Comparable'

```
extension NSNumber: Swift.Comparable {
    var isBool:Bool {
        get {
            let objCType = String.fromCString(self.objCType)
            if (self.compare(trueNumber) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame && objCType == trueObjCType)
                || (self.compare(falseNumber) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame && objCType == falseObjCType){
                    return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that all classes that uses JSON struct has import `import SwiftyJSON`. In my case one class hasn't and that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. If you have swifty.json added to project as source code (without pods) you should remove all the `import SwiftyJSON` lines from your source code.

Answer (score 0):

My app was using that and working with no problems for a long time, and suddenly this problem started to happen. This is my scenario:

1. App compiling and running ok with the SwiftyJSON lib.
2. Started to use unit test in the app. Could launch the app as normal Run and as Test environment both with no compile or run problems.
3. Made some changes in the project (added and removed some of the classes from any target membership).
4. Suddenly the problem started to happen if I tried to run in Test mode, problem not happening for normal Run launch.
5. Made a product->clean and no luck.
6. Went to my version control and observed that adding and removing classes for any target membership changed the file "project.pbxproj" (as it's perfectly logic). But having finally the state of the project as it was in the beginning (step 2), I realized that the order of the files who appeared in "project.pbxproj" file changed, this is, after changes made in step 3, and reverting the state manually in the project to step 2, changes persisted in the file.
7. Well, I tried somenthing: If it's supposed that the project structure now is the same after step 2, I went to version control and ignored changes in "project.pbxproj" file. Then went to xCode and launched a run in Test, and the problem with compiling SwiftyJSON dissapeared

**Conclusion:**
I don't know if this is the cause, but it makes me think that files "declared" in project.pbxproj file are taken to be compiled in somehow order, and seems to be relevant for compiler to take ones before others (I'm not specialist whith compiling processes).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when including SwiftyJson in my test target. If your app target is using SwiftyJson, you should be able to use it in your tests just by importing your app's module as:

```
@testable import <ModuleName>
```